# NSButton in NSToolbar item: click issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton, nstoolbaritem

I want to use a NSButton configured to show only an image in my `NSToolbarItem`. The item is created in IB and the code to add the button to it is:

```
NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc]init];
[button setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"StarEmpty"]];
[button setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"StarFull"]];
[button setImagePosition:NSImageOnly];
[button setBordered:NO];

[self.toolbarItem setView:button];
```

The problem is that when i click on the image instead of the alternate image a lighter background is shown. I link the image to explain the problem.

This is the normal state and it's ok

[image]

This is when i click on it (and not rise the left mouse button)

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix that? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried changing the button type to `NSMomentaryChangeButton`?

> NSMomentaryChangeButton : While the button is held down, the alternate
>   image and alternate title are displayed. The normal image and title
>   are displayed when the button isn’t pressed. This option is called
>   “Momentary Change” in Interface Builder’s Button Inspector. Available
>   in OS X v10.0 and later.